Convex combinations of single-crossing functions
Define a function $f: \Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is single-crossing if $sign[f]$ is monotonic.
I am considering the following conjecture: Let $B$ be a finite set (which could be relaxed?), if $\forall b \in B, a \in \Delta(B), u(b,\theta)-u(a,\theta)$ is single-crossing in $\theta$, then $\forall a',a \in \Delta(B), u(a',\theta)-u(a,\theta)$ is single-crossing in $\theta$, in which $u(a,\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{b \sim a}[u(b,\theta)]$.
The case where $|B|=2$ or $3$ can be easily proved, but I have no good ideas for larger-size cases. I am also aware of certain characterizations of linear combinations single-crossing preserving (e.g., Quah and Strulovici, 2012; Kartik et al., 2023), yet not finding them very helpful.
Any hints or counterexamples would be greatly appreciated!
